# Classify test set using model file weka

Tags: java, prototype, weka

I am creating a prototype for my thesis using the model generated/ trained model in weka. My thesis is about emotion analysis on text.  Now I have the test data/set that I want to classify using the model/trained model.

this is my partial code that reads arff file and have a filter (stringToWordVector):

```
          Classify ct = new Classify(TextJ48.model); // loads model


            string sample = getARFFile();
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(sample);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new java.io.StringReader(buffer.ToString()));
            weka.core.converters.ArffLoader.ArffReader arff = new weka.core.converters.ArffLoader.ArffReader(reader);
            Instances dataRaw = arff.getData();

            StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();
            filter.setInputFormat(dataRaw);
            Instances dataFiltered = Filter.useFilter(dataRaw, filter);
```

When I show the `dataFiltered`it successfully filtered from words to numeric.

this is the `classify` class:

```
 public Classify(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            classifier = (Classifier)weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(filename);
        }
        catch (java.lang.Exception ex)
        {
           lblProgress.Text = ex.getMessage();
        }

        loadAttributes();
        this.fileName = filename;
    }
```

I don't know what to do in `loadAttributes()` My plan is to add all attributes in `FastVector`,I saw in some sources they adds attributes easily because they have a fixed sized attributes, but in my case I have different number of attributes that are based from the text.

Now how do I classify the text that I input using the model.